# TFS Plugin: WorkItemStore.GetWorkItem error

Tags: tfs

I have a server plugin which is using the WorkItemChangedEventHandler to process the workitems for some specific cases. The TFS instance has 3 different collections.

For a specific collection the [GetWorkItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb140393) method is throwing an exception with the `An item with the same key has already been added.` message and it stops the further execution.

```
WorkItemChangedEvent workItemChange = (WorkItemChangedEvent)notificationEventArgs;
WorkItemStore store = Utils.GetWorkItemStore(requestContext);
IntegerField field = workItemChange.CoreFields.IntegerFields[0];
int workitemId = field.NewValue;
store.GetWorkItem(workitemId);
```

I'm using TFS2017 Update 2.